# Is there a strongly typed RedirectToAction in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I wish to do something like this:

```
return RedirectToAction<SomeController>(c => Index(someparameter));
```

How to do this ?

Thanks,
D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a feature of the [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RedirectToAction&referringTitle=Documentation) project.

Just download MvcContrib from [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases), add a reference to MvcContrib.dll in your project and then you should be able to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

is there something wrong with?

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { parameter1 = value, param2 = value2 });
```